# How to speed up code to copy inserted row and clear contents?

Tags: excel, vba, optimization

```vb
Sub CopyInsertRow()

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Font.Bold = False
Cells(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Row, 6).ClearContents
Cells(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Row, 4).ClearContents
Cells(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Row, 2).ClearContents
Cells(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Row, 3).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight

End Sub
```

This macro is to insert a new row, and then copy down and clear some data for a product pricing spreadsheet.

It works, but it is very slow. How can I speed it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit surprised that code is slow unless of course you have a very large table you are inserting the row into. However, maybe this will help.

You want to get rid of all the repetitive code that requires reevaluation.

```
Sub CopyInsertRow()

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False  '*** Turn off screen updating for speed.
 ActiveCell.End(xlToLeft).Select '*** Insure you're in Col A
 
 With ActiveCell
    .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    .EntireRow.Copy .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
    .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Font.Bold = False
    .Offset(1, 5).ClearContents
    .Offset(1, 3).ClearContents
    .Offset(1, 1).ClearContents
    .Offset(1, 2).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
 End With
 
End Sub
```

Note: for the offsets to work with this code you have to start from a known column thus the second statement to get you in column A of the current row.

HTH

Comment: Hey thanks for the  reply. I added the Screen updating off to the original and it is much smoother. Great help!